# Dockerfile special escape symbol

Tags: java, docker, maven

When I use the  command with '--build-arg' to build the docker-image,the spaces in incoming parameters are replaced with a plus sign.

My maven pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.13</version>
    <configuration>
      <repository>192.168.1.200/library/${project.artifactId}</repository>
      <tag>${project.version}</tag>
      <buildArgs>
         <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
         <JVM_OPTS>-Xms300m -Xmx300m</JVM_OPTS>
      </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM 192.168.1.200/library/openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
MAINTAINER gaojiayiner@163.com
LABEL version="1.0.0"
RUN mkdir -p /project && mkdir -p /data
ENV workdir /project
WORKDIR $workdir
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG JVM_OPTS
ENV jvm $JVM_OPTS
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} /project/demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java -jar /project/demo.jar $0 $@"]
```

Terminal execution record:

```
[root@localhost docker-java]# mvn clean package dockerfile:build
[root@localhost docker-java]# docker images
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
192.168.1.200/library/demo      0.0.1-SNAPSHOT      13373a4761a1        3 seconds ago       131MB
192.168.1.200/library/openjdk   8-jdk-alpine        a3562aa0b991        14 months ago       105MB
[root@localhost docker-java]# docker run -d  13373a4761a1
d0b5ce9392b12505419d5648332f204dc3d59327efd389c27a950aa0d1daba35
[root@localhost docker-java]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
d0b5ce9392b1        13373a4761a1             "sh -c 'java -jar /p…"   4 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        8080/tcp                                         reverent_kirch
[root@localhost docker-java]# docker exec -it d0b5ce9392b1 sh
/project # env
jvm=-Xms300m+-Xmx300m
JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.212.04-r0
HOSTNAME=d0b5ce9392b1
```

You can see the code **`jvm=-Xms300m+-Xmx300m`**. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to recompile the [`spotify/dockerfile-maven`](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/) yourself, because the pull request which fixes this bug is not yet merged/accepted.

See "[`spotify/dockerfile-maven` PR 350](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/pull/350)"

It points out to the culprit: [`plugin/dockerfile/BuildMojo.java#encodeBuildParam`](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/blob/986f960cb82085d2f666acd6c2682672d47f5bb0/plugin/src/main/java/com/spotify/plugin/dockerfile/BuildMojo.java#L291-L297)

```java
  private static String encodeBuildParam(Object buildParam) throws MojoExecutionException {
    try {
      return URLEncoder.encode(new Gson().toJson(buildParam), "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      throw new MojoExecutionException("Could not build image", e);
    }
  }
```

> Indeed, we can read [here (class `URLEncoder`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) that `URLEncoder` replaces the space character " " with a plus sign "`+`".
>
> After the encoding, I added a replace to substitute the `+` sign with a space: after the encoding all the plus signs will be already encoded to `/0x2B`, so the ones left are the ones are coming from spaces.

The fix would  include:

```java
      return URLEncoder.encode(
               new Gson().toJson(buildParam), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
             ).replace('+', ' ');
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```